# Automate data import in microsoft dynamics crm

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have written code that imports CSV file records into crm using an existing data map. Now I want this to be run on crm server periodically and automatically.
Guide me what's needed to make it part of crm?

Comment: What have you tried? show us your code. See the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good question.

Comment: His question isn't about the code itself, but how to trigger the code.  CRM has a few mechanisms to do this, with workflow being the most standard and configurable

Answer (score 0):

If your code is a plugin, you can set up a recursive workflow that performs whatever action is needed in order to kick off your code, waits for however long you need, then calls itself again.  There are checks that block infinite looping depending on the how often it calls itself, so be careful of that.

Comment: if its c#, just go ahead and set up a plugin and drop it in the plugin

Comment: How do you want it to run, where is the data imported from?

Comment: data is imported from a csv file generated by online store it contains data of latest orders.
I want this code to be run daily on crm automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't set up these kind of things with a workflow if I can avoid it, you don't want to have stuff ticking away in CRM if you can avoid it plus you have a set number of times a workflow can do recursive calls and then you need to bend stuff to make it work. 
As it is a console program (more or less) and if you have a server to run it on, I'd Schedule it using the the scheduler in WS, or make it as a service. 
This is if you can do that, and as I asked earlier, how do you want to run it and where do you import the data from?

Comment: data is imported from a csv file generated by online store it contains data of latest orders. I want this code to be run daily on crm automatically.

Comment: The question specifically said he wanted it to be part of CRM.  If this process can be done outside of CRM, there are much better tools than workflow that can be used - you mentioned scheduler in WS as one of them.  I would go with a scheduled SSIS job - since it has tools built in to deal with parsing files

Comment: If you want it to run inside CRM you're pretty much stuck with workflows to schedule things, although it is a hazzle to set up, has limited runs and then you need another workflow to trigger something outside the workflow reach to eliminate the check from CRM that it is a recursive WF. You also have limited or no possibility to monitor this.